# Hashicorp Vault password access using Spring boot vault

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

In my application we are making two calls from my app for getting secrets from Vault, as shown below:

**Test in Postman**

Login to Vault : POST call to https::/v1/auth/approle/login -- It will take role_id and secret_id as payload and response will be client_token.

Fetch secrets : GET call to https::v1//utlfddfgddbs159.as.dev.net/static-creds/abc01view_appuser -- It will take headers as X-Vault-Token

{
"request_id": "....",
"lease_id": "",
"renewable": false,
"lease_duration": 0,
"data": {
"last_vault_rotation": "....",
"password": "BCNWXUK_z8fwdAchbPx5RTfHAasd32223",
"rotation_period": 15552000,
"ttl": 14949149,
"username": "appuser"
},
"wrap_info": null,
"warnings": null,
"auth": null
}

Now I am use Spring Cloud Vault Dependency to integrate in my application.

Pls suggest if I am missing anything configuration

Dependency Used

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

File: bootsrap.yml
cloud:
    vault:      
      enabled: true
      host: <host>
      port: 8200
      scheme: https
      namespace: ..
      order: 1
      kv-version: 1
      authentication: APPROLE      
      app-role:
        role-id: .....
        secret-id: .....    
        role: .....
```

I am unable to get password using **spring-cloud-starter-vault-config** but when I am executing using postman, able to get password from **Hashicrop vault**

Comment: Maybe you are missing base-path of utlfddfgddbs159.as.dev.net/static-creds/abc01view_appuser, spring must be aware of the path to get secrets from

Comment: base path is 

     `host: <host>
      port: 8200
      scheme: https`

Answer (score -1):

Create customised jar using Environmentpostprocessor to get data from property file and called hashicrop vault to get respective details